# How to handle contradiction between routes?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

My route file:

```
resources :users do
  ...
  resources :subscriptions do
      post 'add', on: :collection
      put 'pause', on: :member
      put 'cancel', on: :member
      put 'resume', on: :member
      put 'update', on: :member 
  end
  ...
end
```

When I'm trying to test request of **GET** for `:show` of subscription using rspec it gives me

```
ActionController::RoutingError:
   No route matches [GET] "/api/v1/users/1774/subscriptions/257/update"
```

I have noticed that it is automatically appending `/update` to the end of it.
This is my test:

```
describe "GET /api_v1/subscriptions/:id" do
  it "get subscription details" do
    get api_v1_user_subscription_path(@user1.id,@subscription1.id), headers: admin_headers
    expect(response).to be_success
    expect(response.content_type).to eq("application/json")
  end
end
```

And this is my `rake routes` for subscription:

```
 add_api_v1_user_subscriptions POST     /api/v1/users/:user_id/subscriptions/add(.:format)                     api/v1/subscriptions#add
 pause_api_v1_user_subscription PUT      /api/v1/users/:user_id/subscriptions/:id/pause(.:format)               api/v1/subscriptions#pause
 cancel_api_v1_user_subscription PUT      /api/v1/users/:user_id/subscriptions/:id/cancel(.:format)              api/v1/subscriptions#cancel
 resume_api_v1_user_subscription PUT      /api/v1/users/:user_id/subscriptions/:id/resume(.:format)              api/v1/subscriptions#resume
 api_v1_user_subscription PUT      /api/v1/users/:user_id/subscriptions/:id/update(.:format)              api/v1/subscriptions#update
 api_v1_user_subscriptions GET      /api/v1/users/:user_id/subscriptions(.:format)                         api/v1/subscriptions#index
                           POST     /api/v1/users/:user_id/subscriptions(.:format)                         api/v1/subscriptions#create
                           GET      /api/v1/users/:user_id/subscriptions/:id(.:format)                     api/v1/subscriptions#show
                           PATCH    /api/v1/users/:user_id/subscriptions/:id(.:format)                     api/v1/subscriptions#update
                           PUT      /api/v1/users/:user_id/subscriptions/:id(.:format)                     api/v1/subscriptions#update
                           DELETE   /api/v1/users/:user_id/subscriptions/:id(.:format)                     api/v1/subscriptions#destroy
```

I noticed that using `api_v1_user_subscription_path` is the source of the problem but i didn't understand how could it make a problem although the route that includes `/update` in the end is `put` and i'm sending `get` request.

I got two solution for this problem:

1- to change the name of the `update` route inside the subscription resource and it worked

2- to remove `update` route because `resources :subscription` make it for us but without `/update` in the end.

The problem was that my PM(project manager) didn't accept both solutions.
So is there anyone who can help me that make routes works without touching `put 'update', on: :member`?

Thanks

Comment: Why do you use a `member` for `update`? Why don't you just use the default [nested resources](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#nested-resources) for `update`? What do you try to achieve?

Comment: I got your point and that's exactly what i'm explaining to him ... to just use nested resources but he is refusing, He needs some route that calls #update function which have trailing `/update` at the end.

Comment: Interesting setup in which a project manager has the ability to reject a working solution just because he does like the internal implementation. Why is that even his business?

Answer (score 0):

This is a way that satisfied my PM:

```
#config/routes
resources :subscriptions do
      post 'add', on: :collection
      put 'pause', on: :member
      put 'cancel', on: :member
      put 'resume', on: :member
end
resources :subscriptions, only: [] do
      put 'update', on: :member
end
```

This solution worked but i hope if there is another way to solve this.